# How to get the last chunk of a csv file using Pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Suppose I have a csv file containing 5 rows.

Now I iterate over this file using a chunksize of 2.

```
data = pd.read_csv(data_name, header=None, iterator=True, chunksize=2)
```

Suppose I am doing some magic on this data chunk and appending it to another csv file.

```
processed_data.to_csv(fname, index=None, mode="a")
```

**Problem:** The last row is not written.

I do not know how to solve this problem. Can someone help?

I need to use chunks because I don't have enough **RAM**.

I can not use `chunksize=1`, because opening/closing a file is too time consuming.

Comment: There must be a problem somewhere during your "magic". You will be able to iterate over all rows using this method. Perhaps you should update your answer to show an example of how you go from data to processed_data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running out of memory I would use blaze for this type of data.
https://blaze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ooc.html

Then you don't have to mess with the chunksize.